# Pyshp shapefile reader not working

Tags: python, shapefile

import shapefile

```
r = shapefile.Reader("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\py\mis.dbf")
```

That is as far as I get, must be something simple I don't know about. I have already spent a embarrassing amount of time on this little thing. Could one of you more knowlegeable ones tell me what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're good to go unless you're getting an error that you didn't mention.

First of all you're looking at the dbf file which contains the shapefile attributes (similar to a spreadsheet).  But that doesn't matter because the Reader ignores extensions and will try to find the .shp and .shx files as well containing the geometry and geometry record index as well.

If you're just interested in the attributes try the following after you above example:

```
# Print the dbf field names
print [f[0] for f in r.fields]
# Print the first record:
print r.record(0)

# Loop through all the records using an interator:
for rec in r.iterRecords(): print rec
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problem by changing " to '

Comment: I am assuming it has something to do with which version of Python I am using which is 3.3   I should of mentioned that detail. Thanks for the piece of code, I was wondering how to do that.